# Is there a way to store MySQL statements in PHP in the Functions.php file?

Tags: php, mysql, function

Let's say I have a piece of code that is getting all records from a particular table.  Such as:

```
mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
$query_getTechs = "SELECT * FROM zip_tech ORDER BY tech_name ASC";
$getTechs = mysql_query($query_getTechs, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getTechs = mysql_fetch_assoc($getTechs);
$totalRows_getTechs = mysql_num_rows($getTechs);
```

Is there a way to make this a function where the table name and sort by column are part of the function's arguments?  So I could put something such as:

```
get_records('zip_tech','tech_name');
```

I end up with a lot of these on some things I'm trying to build as I learn PHP.  It seems like having to use blocks of code like that repeatedly makes things more convuluted and less clean looking.

Comment: **Note**: Use mysqli_* or PDO functions instead of mysql_* (deprecated)

Comment: of course, you would have a function like `get_records($table, $column)`. Oh yeah mysql is bad, mkay.

Comment: I think you need to read up on [functions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php)

Comment: Rather than rolling your own on this, you might look at a PHP framework like ZendFramework or CakePHP to get your code more organized.

Comment: Yeah I've heard about mysqli.  Whenever I write mysql_ do I just change the front part to mysqli_ and that's it?  I've been reading on functions.  But I wasn't sure if doing that would make things vulnerable or if storing things like that in a file would create problems.  I'll look at CakePHP.  That will help me learn to organize code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for are, well, functions.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php
A function for get_records would look something like this:

```
function get_records($from, $order){
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM '.$from.' ORDER BY '.$order.' ASC';
    //whatever else you wanted
    return $query;
    }
```

And you'd call it like this:

```
$query = get_records('zip_tech','tech_name');
```

You could also create a function without the return value, that preforms what you need. And call it by just invoking the function name and parameters.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty easy to understand.  I've been reading about functions, but I was approaching it much, much more complicated than you made it.  The only thing I don't get is why are there periods on either side of the variables?  Does doing that have a name so I can learn about that also?

Comment: IT's called string concatenation, and it's one of a few operations you can preform on strings.


See examples here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: Yeah I know about those.  I didn't know it was the same thing in this example.  Why are they necessary in the statement?  Nevermind, maybe it does make sense.  If I was writing a url, I might have a part that goes echo `'<a href="newpage.php?id='. $id.'">Go Here</a>';`  So this is doing the same thing?  It is saying FROM (and then) $from (and then) ORDER BY?

Comment: (I cannot format comments. :C)
Yes, that is doing the same thing. Logically, what the . operator does is combine the strings together at the point where the . is

For instance 

$a = "Hi ";
$b = "Bob";
$c = "!";
echo $a.$b.$c;
echo $a.$c;
echo $b.$c;

This would result in the output

Hi bob!
Hi !
bob!